# How to include 3 background images in a single css?

Tags: php, html, css

Here's a piece of my navigation code:

```
<? if($page == ""){ ?>  
    <li>
        <a href="<? echo $site;?>" id="on" style="background-image:url(images/logonav_onright.png) right no-repeat;">Home</a>
    </li>  
<? }else{ ?>   
    <li>
        <a href="<? echo $site;?>">Home</a>
    </li>   
<? } ?>
```

I want that `#on` to include 3 images basically:

1. With `repeat-x`.  (Which is actually the `#on`)
2. Left side of the nav button.
3. Right side of the nav button.

I tried some solutions I found online, although none seem to work. 
Is there a way to do it without wrapping each nav with 2 additional `div` tags?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a solution that doesn't involve adding more elements. Unfortunately, only one background image can be applied per element via CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You would do it like so:

```
background-image: url(sheep.png), url(betweengrassandsky.png);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

There's some more information on that [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/), but as a heads-up, it's a CSS3 property only.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want are [CSS Sliding Doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/).